# Injecting user specific singleton classes in a session

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, saas

I am basically working on a project to convert a standalone product into a SaaS application. The current project has few singleton classes.

Now my query is

In SaaS, there will be multiple users under different customers accessing the same application. The singleton classes need to be customer specific for each user.

eg. LicenseManager class for users of a particular company A should get singleton class instance class1 of LicenseManager while users of other company say company B should get singleton instance class2 . Similarly the singleton DBManager class instance for users of a particular company should be company specific.

Is this possible using Spring or any other framework ? Is it possible to have something like a parent session and a child session under that parent session ?

Comment: There is no such a thing as a "static class". There are static inner classes, but that's a different thing. What are you trying to do?

Comment: please check i have edited

Comment: This is really broad. It would depend on technologies you're using and the current architecture. The only thing that's possible to say is that you'll need to convert the singletons to something else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following are my suggestions. Based up on these you can come up with an appropriate solution.

1. Convert these classes as non-static. Have some logic to create
   instance of these class using an abstract factory for each customer
   based up on preference. Use corresponding instance for each
   customer.
2. Convert these classes as abstract. Have child classes for
   each customer type. Use Factory method to instantiate appropriate
   child class. You can use dependency injection if you are on Spring
   framework.
3. Keep these classes as static. Move the configurations
   (member variables) logic to separate Configuration utility, where
   you should return appropriate configuration to static classes based
   up on customer.